# Problem using bickham

Tags: fonts, metafont

Some time ago, I posted [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167243/changing-mathcal-settings-latex). I forgot about it, and it popped up just yesterday thanks toa  comment. It is in a sorry state, and I have been suggested to ask a new one with the only issue that is left there. Which is the following. I tried using the `bickham` package, getting errors related to a non-found `tfm` file. More precisely, let me paste an excerpt of the question here.

< Excerpt >

I really do not know what went wrong when I tried `bickham`. All I can see is that one of my files currently reads:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,fontinst,bickham}
    \installfont{bickham}{latin}{t1}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{}
    
    \begin{document}
    $$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$$
    $$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$$
    $$\mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$$
    $$\mathcal{a\,b\,c\,d\,e\,f\,g\,h\,i\,j\,k\,l\,m\,n\,o\,p\,q\,r\,s\,t\,u\,v\,w\,x\,y\,z}$$
    \end{document}
```

And compiling that yields:

[…]

```
     This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
     restricted \write18 enabled.
     entering extended mode
     (./mathcal_fontinst.tex
     LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
     Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
     Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/fontinst/base/fontinst.sty
     No file fontinst.rc.
     ) (/Users/michelegorini/Library/texmf/tex/latex/bickham/bickham.sty
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
     (./mathcal_fontinst.aux)
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
     (/Users/michelegorini/Library/texmf/tex/latex/bickham/ubickham.fd)
     kpathsea: Running mktextfm bickham-r
     mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bickham-r
     This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded base=mf)

     kpathsea: Running mktexmf bickham-r

     ! I can't find file `bickham-r'.
     <*> ...jfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bickham-r
                                                  
     Please type another input file name
     ! Emergency stop.
     <*> ...jfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bickham-r
                                                  
     Transcript written on mfput.log.
     grep: bickham-r.log: No such file or directory
     mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input bickham-r' failed to make bickham-r.tfm.
     kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

     ./mathcal_fontinst.tex:6: Font U/bickham/m/n/10=bickham-r at 10.0pt not loadabl
     e: Metric (TFM) file not found.
     <to be read again> 
                        relax 
     extract@font ...ont font@name external@font relax 
                                                       font@name relax csname f@e...

     define@newfont ...ong@fontshape else extract@font 
                                                       fi endgroup 
     pickup@font ...ifx font@name relax define@newfont 
                                                       fi 
     getanddefine@fonts ...size endcsname }pickup@font 
                                                       let textfont@name font@nam...

     select@group ...me c@mv@math@version endcsname }#3
                                                       globaldefs @ne math@fonts ...
     l.6 $$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
                                               $$
     ?
```

Greek, Greek, Gibberish. That is with the `\installfont` commented. Uncomment it, and this is what happens:

```
     This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
     restricted \write18 enabled.
     entering extended mode
     (./mathcal_fontinst.tex
     LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
     Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
     Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/fontinst/base/fontinst.sty
     No file fontinst.rc.
     ) (/Users/michelegorini/Library/texmf/tex/latex/bickham/bickham.sty
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
     (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
     ./mathcal_fontinst.tex:3: Too many }'s.
     \input_metrics ...t \curr_file_list \else \egroup 
                                                       \bgroup #1\expandafter \pr...

     \installfont ...al =\x_relax \input_metrics {}{#2}
                                                       \etxtovpl {#3}{#1}\install...
     l.3 ...llfont{bickham}{latin}{t1}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{}
                                                  
     ?
```

< /Excerpt >

It seems that `tfm` file just won't be found. THe strange thing is, if I open the folder of the `bickham` package, I see lots of `tfm`s, precisely the folder contains the files in the following screenshot:

[image]

That folder, however, is definitely found, since the package is called. And a few `.fd`s from the folder are also loaded. I have been told I should install the fonts, but if I have the `fd` and `tfm` files TeX should not have to know whether I have the fonts installed on my computer since those are the files it uses. So why is this `tfm` file simply not found?

Comment: You don't want to load `fontinst`. You don't want the `\installfont` line. These are used to generate the `.tfm`, `.vf` etc. in the first place. `bickham` already provides those. And please don't use `$$` in LaTeX documents - it is long deprecated. ***But***, as I said before, none of this will work without the fonts themselves. You need to acquire the fonts from Adobe and produce type1 versions for TeX to use. The `.tfm` files etc. are enough for TeX itself. You can produce a `.dvi` that way. However, without the fonts, all you'll have is boxes. Right now, you have information about the ...

Comment: ***size*** of each glyph in the font. That's what the `.afm` files provide. This gets used in the `.tfm` files for TeX. Regular LaTeX uses that information in typesetting - it just treats everything as a box, so it only needs to know the size of the boxes, when it should move the boxes a little bit relative to each other etc. It doesn't need to know what is in the boxes. But you don't have the glyphs i.e. the little picture of each character in the font. This is needed to view the `.dvi`, convert it to `.ps` or, in the case of pdfLaTeX, to produce the PDF directly.

Comment: For pdfLaTeX, you'd also need to tell TeX about the `.map` file if you've not installed the fonts. That's easy but, as I say, there really isn't any point since pdfTeX needs the type1 versions for the PDF.

Comment: @cfr I read TFM not found. So why is it not found? I mean OK maybe I can't produce a PDF with only those files, but the error should not say TFM file not found, but rather something different. So why can it not find the TFM? As for the `$$`, don't worry, I've stopped, but this file is very old, and there is no point editing it now.

Comment: Also, my Font Book says I have a Bickham Script MM font.

Comment: And I've just used it with XeTeX.

Comment: Also, I get more or less the same result by loading just `amsfonts` and declaring a math alphabet for `bickham` with code copied from the package.

Comment: XeTeX uses your system fonts. TeX and pdfTeX cannot do that. So having it in Font Book is relevant in the first case but not the second. To use it with XeTeX, you don't need any of that stuff from the `bickham` package anyway. It isn't failing to find the `.tfm`. It is failing to find an `.mf` because you've not added the `.map` fragment. You can say `\pdfmapfile{+bickham.map}` and it will stop trying to use a metafont version. But it won't find the type1 version unless you ensure that's available.

Comment: But if «it isn't failing to find the `.tfm`», why does it say `Font U/bickham/m/n/10=bickham-r at 10.0pt not loadabl
     e: Metric (TFM) file not found.`?

Comment: It is failing to find it but this is because it thinks it is supposed to make it first. So it tries to make it and then it looks *there*. But the problem is that it cannot make it. And it can't make it because there is no `.mf`. And it thinks it is meant to make it because you haven't told it otherwise. That's why you need it to read the `.map` file fragment. By default, it assumes it is dealing with a metafont font unless it knows otherwise. If the font is type1 or truetype or whatever, it knows otherwise from `.map` files.

Comment: Umm… `pdfTeX warning: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file bickham.map): cannot open font map f
ile`. After adding `\pdfmapfile{+bickham.map}`, that is.

Comment: But you have the file in your working directory?

Comment: I downloaded the package, created a test document in the unzipped directory and ran pdfLaTeX. It found the map file fragment fine. Of course, I got a fatal error preventing compilation as I don't have the type1 fonts, but it found the map file.

Comment: Well the `.map` is together with `bickham.sty` which is found. It is in the local branch, where I put new packages or other files that should be visible system-wide.

Comment: _But_ putting the document in the directory of the package changes the behaviour to `!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file BickhamScriptPro-Semibold.pfb): canno
t open Type 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`.

Comment: However, putting the `.map` (a duplicate of it) in the document's directory changes nothing.

Comment: You mean you didn't have the files from the package in your working directory before?! How was it finding the `.sty` file in that case? Note that the error you are now seeing is normal - you don't have the type1 fonts any more than I do. If you remove the map line and compile with `latex`, you can produce a perfectly good `.dvi`. You'll just get errors when you try to view it because you don't have the fonts.

Comment: Slightly unrelated: I updated to TeX Live 2015 (or whatever there is just above 2014), but TeX is still loading the old versions of the packages. How can I correct that?

Comment: You know, there is a directory which is there precisely for new packages to be found by TeX. On my mac, it is `Home/Library/texmf/tex/latex`. In there, I have the `bickham` directory in which all the files in the screenshot you see in the question are located.

Comment: If TL 2015 has been released, you are better informed than me. As far as I know, TL 2014 is the latest. Re. putting the `.map` in the document's directory: of course, that's not enough. If you don't have the other files, it won't find them. Either you have all the relevant files in your directory, or you install them in a `TEXMF` tree properly. Otherwise, they won't be found.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"? Just putting them there isn;t enough? FOr a package, it is. What should I do?

Comment: Ah no, I was misled by the names I gave the aliases of the directories where the standard packages are :). I have 2012, 2013 and 2014, and 2014 is being used.

Comment: You have to install the package properly. LaTeX looks for particular file types in particular places. It will look for the `.sty` file and `.fd` files there but it will not look for `.map` or `.vf` or `.tfm` files. Look at where these files are in your main `TEXMF` tree and mirror that structure if you want to do it that way. (Unless you are planning to acquire the fonts, I wouldn't bother but it is obviously your call.)

Comment: It seems I do not have any other .map file. WHat other kinds of files are in the same place as `.map`s?

Comment: Ah no wait. Found them. `texmf-dist/fonts/map`. Copied the structure into the local branch, i.e. created `Home/Library/texmf/texmf-dist/map`. Put the `.map` there. Created, always in that `texmf-dist`, the `vf` and `afm` folders, and put relevant files there. Result: no change. I think I'm giving up. Tomorrow, I'll write up an answer explaining what is going on here, so this question is finally considered as answered and bumped off the unanswered list. Of course, you are more qualified for that, and I would thank you if you did that. Right now it's bedtime, so goodnight and thanks.

Comment: `.../texmf-dist/` is the root of the tree. Skip it. You can't skip the directories below. You need e.g. `fonts/map/dvips/bickham/bickham.map`. Similarly for the other files. If you say `kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN` and compare with `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME` you will get the roots of the two trees. The structure beneat those roots needs to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Statement of Limitation

This answer concerns the use of type1 fonts with TeX and pdfTeX. Claims do not apply to XeTeX or LuaTeX. Nor am I concerned here with the use of METAFONT fonts. These topics are mentioned only incidentally. If you want information about the preparation, installation or use of fonts in any of these situations, this answer will only confuse you!

## Answer

The code in the question reflects considerable confusion. The code is a LaTeX document which tries to call [fontinst](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontinst) as a package. This confuses 2 fundamentally distinct activities and omits a third:

1. Preparing the files which LaTeX (and TeX) need to use a font.
2. Installing a font together with the files prepared to support its use.
3. Using an installed font in a document.

When you write a LaTeX (or TeX) document, 1 and 2 must already have been completed.

`fontinst` is a package which you can use to complete some of the steps required at stage 1. On its own, it is not sufficient to complete stage 1. Moreover, it has nothing to do with stages 2 or 3. `fontinst`'s work is done ***before*** completion of stage 1.

It should never be called as a package in a regular LaTeX document.

Here is what CTAN has to say about it:

> TeX macros for con­vert­ing Adobe Font Met­ric files to TeX met­ric
>   and vir­tual font for­mat. Fon­tinst helps mainly with the num­ber
>   crunch­ing and shov­el­ling parts of font in­stal­la­tion. This means
>   in prac­tice that it cre­ates a num­ber of files which give the TeX
>   met­rics (and re­lated in­for­ma­tion) for a font fam­ily that (La)TeX
>   needs to do any type­set­ting in these fonts. Fon­tinst fur­ther­more
>   makes it easy to cre­ate fonts con­tain­ing glyphs from more than one
>   base font, tak­ing ad­van­tage of (e.g.) "ex­pert" font sets.
>
> Fon­tinst can­not ex­am­ine files to see if they con­tain any use­ful
>   in­for­ma­tion, nor au­to­mat­i­cally search for files or work with
>   bi­nary file for­mats; those tasks must nor­mally be done man­u­ally
>   or with the help of some other tool, such as the pltotf and vp­tovf
>   pro­grams.

When you download a font support package, however, stage 1 is typically already complete. Indeed, the whole point of using such a package is that you don't have to worry about stage 1.

Once you have `bickham`, therefore, you only need to worry about stages 2 and 3. At least, that would be the case with a typical font support package. In the case of `bickham`, there is the additional requirement to ***obtain the fonts from Adobe***. Without those fonts, nothing is actually going to work.

However, if you insist on continuing anyway because you either have no interest in producing actual documents or you just don't believe me when I tell you you need a copy of the fonts for this to work, you may proceed as follows.

### Quick Method

I use this when creating a font support package for testing. It is quick and saves installing and reinstalling when I find I've made a mistake.

Put a simple test document and the `.map`, `.fd`, `.tfm`, `.pfb` and, if applicable `.vf` and `.sty` files into a directory together with a test file:

- Of course, if you do not have the `.pfb` files, you can't put them in the directory. That's a problem, as will become obvious.

In the case of `bickham`, for pdfLaTeX use

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{+bickham.map}
\usepackage{bickham}
\begin{document}
    abc $\mathcal{abc}$ abc
\end{document}
```

For LaTeX use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bickham}
\begin{document}
    abc $\mathcal{abc}$ abc
\end{document}
```

### *What happens if the `.pfb` is missing?*

In this case:

- pdfLaTeX will encounter a fatal error the first time you try to use one of the fonts. This is because it cannot produce the PDF without the type1 font your document requires.
- LaTeX, however, will successfully produce a `.dvi`.

Why the difference? TeX regards the entire universe as made up of boxes. Different boxes have different heights, widths and depths, and sometimes there are rules about what to do when a particular box is followed by another one. The `.tfm` and `.vf` files provide information about the boxes relevant to typesetting the fonts supported by `bickham`. The `.tfm`s, in particular, tell TeX the dimensions of the box for each character in the font supported by the package. They also provide the kerning information. For example, a `.tfm` for a particular font might tell TeX that if the character in slot 131 is followed by the character in slot 126, then the box for the latter should be shifted a little bit to the left or right. They might even tell TeX that the two boxes should be replaced by the box for the character in slot 45.

As far as TeX is concerned, `.tfm` files just are fonts. That's because fonts are just information about boxes.

TeX doesn't know or care that fonts typically also contain ***pictures*** of each character - glyphs. It doesn't need the glyphs to figure out how to arrange the boxes.

So, when you use LaTeX to compile the example above, TeX finds everything it needs. It produces the `.dvi` file just fine. Only when you come to view the document will you get errors. Specifically, your viewer will complain that it can neither find not construct the fonts the document is asking for.

So the example above produces the following:

[image: the bickham gap]

The characters in Computer Modern display fine, of course. The gap is where the `bickham` glyphs should be displayed. Note that the correct amount of space is left for them (I assume) since TeX knows how big each character's box is and whether adjustments are needed when `b` follows `a` or `c` follows `b`. But without the glyph itself, your viewer can't show you the ***content*** of those boxes.

In contrast, pdfLaTeX encounters a fatal error because pdfTeX puts the pictures in the document. It uses both information about the boxes from the `.tfm` files *and* the pictures from the `.pfb`. If it cannot find the type1 font, therefore, compilation fails.

***There is therefore no point in installing `bickham` unless you have the type1 fonts available or like playing with invisible boxes in `.dvi`s.***

### Installation

Nonetheless, if for some bizarre reason you want to do this, the recommendation is to install into your local `texmf` tree.

```
kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL
```

will tell you were this is. Probably `/usr/local/texlive/texm-local`.

Start by downloading `bickham.tds.zip` from CTAN. Copy this file to the directory you identified as `TEXMFLOCAL`. (You will need, probably, to authenticate to do this.)

Change to `TEXMFLOCAL`, unzip and install:

```
cd $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
sudo unzip bickham.tds.zip
sudo rm bickham.tds.zip
sudo mktexlsr $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)
```

***Make sure that you have eradicated all traces of `bickham` from `TEXMFHOME`.***

```
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=bickham.map
```

Now you can generate fatal errors or play with invisible boxes without needing the package files in your working directory. Congratulations.

You now modify the pdfLaTeX example to delete the `\pdfmapfile` line i.e. the example for pdfLaTeX is now identical to that for LaTeX. This is because you've added the `.map` file fragment from `bickham` to the files which pdfTeX uses to map from TeX fonts to type1 fonts. (Basically, a kind of directory which tells pdfTeX where the pictures are kept for each such font it knows about.)

- Note that this will break things when you try to use the fonts because, as mentioned several times already, pdfTeX will look for the `.pfb` files. Using `updmap-sys` to enable the `bickham.map` fragment or adding it using `\pdfmapfile` is essentially telling pdfTeX fibs. You are claiming to have font files you don't. So it is no use complaining when it fails to compile with fatal errors. You've deliberately given it a phone book with spurious information. When it goes AWOL to look for Santa at the North Pole, the responsibility will be entirely yours.