# Bickham font installation

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, mactex, installing-fonts

I'm having some issues regarding the installation of the package Bickham (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bickham). I'm using the MacTeX-2016 distribution.

First of all, the installation of this font require (according to the package documentation, http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/fonts/bickham/bickham-doc.pdf) the generation of pbf fonts by the commands

```
 /usr/texbin/cfftot1 BickhamScriptPro-Regular.otf -o BickhamScriptPro-Regular.pfb
 /usr/texbin/cfftot1 BickhamScriptPro-Bold.otf -o BickhamScriptPro-Bold.pfb
 /usr/texbin/cfftot1 BickhamScriptPro-Semibold.otf -o BickhamScriptPro-Semibold.pfb
```

However there is no folder /usr/texbin . In /usr there are just bin, lib, libexec, local, sbin, share, standalone and X11

Now, the second step is to make the usual installation procedure as in [Font installation in TeXShop on a Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49736/font-installation-in-texshop-on-a-mac) and [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation) . However the command

```
 sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=bickham.map
```

doesn't create any map files. Maybe the second step depends on the first, which I could never conclude and this would explain the incorrect output

Maybe a related question is [Problem using bickham](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232882/problem-using-bickham) , however it just confused me more as the author of the answer already warned in the beginning.

Thanks in advance.

Meanwhile also posted at [LaTeX-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=97540#p97540).

Comment: I don't know why they tell to use `/usr/texbin/cfftot1`; just `cfftot1` suffices.

Comment: @egreg It's written in the package documentation to add /usr/texbin/cfftot1 instead of cfftot1 just to make sure in case one is using TL. However as I said above, I don't have this folder.

Comment: Well, they're wrong, aren't they? If from your terminal you're able to run `pdflatex`, then you can also run `cfftot1`.

Comment: @egreg Well, let me rephrase it properly. It's written: "If you use TEX Live, a symlink to cfftot1 should be located in /usr/texbin and this directory should be in your PATH. If not, replace each occurrence of cfftot1 with /usr/texbin/cfftot1."

Comment: That's no longer true: since El Capitan was issued, the symbolic link cannot be `/usr/texbin/` and now it is `/Library/TeX/texbin`. But, as I said, if you are able to run TeX programs from your shell, you need no prefix for calling `cfftot1`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for this remark. However I get the error "No such file or directory". I don't know where I should put these .otf files. Actually I cannot find these files in the package.

Comment: Do you get any output from `type pdflatex` or `type cfftot1`?

Comment: @egreg Sure. I've got "cfftot1 is hashed (/Library/TeX/texbin/cfftot1)".

Comment: Save your hassle: use `xelatex`, forget about installing fonts.