# Using bickham font in PDF latex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, overleaf

Given that I have the font downloaded to my computer (in both a `.ttf` and `.otf` file), how might I import the Bickham font class into my file? I am currently using PDF latex, not XeLaTeX, and cannot make the switch from `fontenc` to `fontspec`. I was hoping there was a simple command I can input (similar to a package, say) after having imported the bickham font style to the doc.

I tried using an answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232882/problem-using-bickham/232995#232995), but when I use

`\pdfmapfile{+bickham.map} \usepackage{bickham}`

I get an error saying the `.sty` file was not found. I can convert to a `.pbf` but this does not help.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) is a related question, addressing the more general issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which distribution do you have?

Comment: you say that you have downloaded the font to your computer but you have tagged the question overleaf which implies that you are running tex on that hosted service not on your machine, in which case you would need to upload the font to your overleaf project (whre you could use the ttf or otf directly using lualatx or xelatex)

Comment: also the ctan bickham package description says it is not in texlive (so not on overleaf) but that the mathalpha package (by the same author) supports these fonts now (if you have the font), that is in overleaf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have uploaded the font (both .ttf and .otf) to the main document. I still get the .sty file. I will try, now, using mathalpha. (Edit: after putting the mathalpha package before +bickham.map and `\usepackage{bickham}`, the result is still the same.) How can I change the Tex Live?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have used bickham before on XeLaTeX from overleaf, but for other reasons I prefer to use PDFLaTeX. My question was, in particular, asking for a way to use bickham on overleaf without changing from PDFLaTeX to XeLaTeX.

Comment: if you are using ttf or otf then you just need the generic fontspec package and lualatex or xelatex (not pdflatex) if you ar using pdftex then you will need to upload all the support files that come with the bickham or mathalpha packages, vf files tfm files map files as well as possible pfb files, whatever it needs. Certainly it will be dozens of files not just one

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. Do you happen to know the exact files/where I can find them?

Comment: no I don't have the font or the bickham package, I guess I have mathalpha but not really easy see how to unpick exactly what that would need to use bickham but I would start from there as that will be in overleaf so you should just have to supply the fonts hopefully the tfm and vf files are there already but I haven't checked. (You must really like the font, getting an openype font working in pdftex just basically never seems worth the trouble since unicode texs became available)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there anyway to make an overleaf file with XeLaTeX and the font included and then add that to the PDF version? I doubt it would be this simple...

Comment: sure, yes: you could use standalone class to make a pdf with just one character using xelatex then include that into pdlatex with something like `\includegraphics[height=1ex]{a.pdf}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Cannot believe that worked. Thanks so much for your help. Final question: do you know how I scale `ex` to be the same size relative to `9pt` letters?

Comment: ex is the height of an x in the current font  so for capital letters maybe 1.4ex or something

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks again for your help.